# How to split a git repository into two but keep the git history for both?

Tags: git, repository

I have a repository that is totally cluttered and is a very good candidate to be split up and separated to decrease CI build times. However I want to keep the current Git History in both while removing the parts I do not want anymore from either repository by commit these major changes to them.

I wonder if there is a proper way to do that. I thought about forking two new repositories from the current one where each is changing in terms of removing the components they do not want to keep? Is this a way to do that? Or what is the best practise here?

Comment: "*forking two new repositories from the current one … remove the components they do not want to keep*" Yes, that's the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it.  I will be using original-repo, new-repo1 and new-repo2 as stand-ins for your repositories:

```
cd ~
git clone original-repo new-repo1
cd new-repo1
git rm -r stuff-you-dont-want
git commit

cd ~
git clone original-repo new-repo2
cd new-repo2
git rm -r different-stuff-you-dont-want
git commit
```

Now you'll have two different folders with two diverging copies of the repo.  You can then update the origin remotes to point to the different remote repos (e.g. on Github).

```
cd ~/new-repo1
git remote set-url origin new-repo1-url
git push -u origin master

cd ~/new-repo2
git remote set-url origin new-repo2-url
git push -u origin master
```